# qtcreator can't find qt

Tags: linux, qt

I'm running linux mint 17.1 cinnamon 64bit and installed qtcreator from repo, The problem is I don't find any qt version in Tools->options->qt versions.

I tried downloading qt from here http://www.qt.io/download/, I installed the community version in home and removed qtcreator that was installed from repo, I also removed qt4-doc and qtcreator-doc and relied on the installation in home directory.

I also tried installing qmake version 5 from repo but qtcreator still doesn't detect any qt, I thought of adding it manually by browsing to /usr/bin/qmake but it said it's not an executable.

I need the program for a university project which is a simulation program, so basically , it's a desktop application. I'm planning to use qt Quick project type but as I said, no qt version detected, although gcc compilers are detected(I installed them from repo).

### PS

I have qtcreator 3.3.1 based on qt 5.4(as the about says).

### Edit

I tried removing the installation from home folder and instead of installing qtcreator, I ran `apt install qt-sdk` which apparently installs qtcreator too, but I still find no qt version in Tools->options->qt versions.

Comment: If you have `qmake` command available from the command line then you can do `which qmake` and use that path to add in the Qt distribution.

Comment: Thanks @JozefLegény but I found the answer, the reason I didn't post it is a moderator's answer on my meta question to wait the end of the bounty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem solved, for anyone else follow these steps:

1-install qt-sdk, in mint(or ubuntu) it's done like this:
`apt install qt-sdk` or `sudo apt-get install qt-sdk`, this might take a while.

2-in qtcreator select Tools->options->qt versions.

3-click Add and browse to where qmake is located, on my device it was in /usr/share/qt4/bin/qmake. On other distros(other than mint and ubuntu) browse to where it's located(sorry don't know where).

4-now you have qt, although you might see a warning sign on the version added, it simply works for qtwidgets project with opengl(tried it myself).

5-last thing is to go to kits tab and select the qt version you added in any kit you want to add, for example in the Desktop kit i selected qt version and chose the version I added.

### ps

the qt version I use is 4.8, for version 5+ it may be the same. and don't install qtcreator package but qt-sdk, qt-sdk will bring qtcreator along with many tools.